# Do PCs earn an income besides what they earn while adventuring?

Tags: wfrp-2e, warhammer

In Warhammer FRP 2nd edition your character is an adventurer (duh), yet they also have a career which they've been (and are still) supposedly pursuing, especially inbetween adventures.

You know, by day you're a barber-surgeon pulling teeth and treating the sick, in the evening and during holidays you go and free your kidnapped aunt from the clutches of vile cultists who also happen to have some gold which you reappropriate for the betterment of society from their dead bodies. Next Monday you're back at the barber shop curing dandruff and whatnot, for which services the citizens of the Empire pay you, as usual. Or maybe you're a noble and you're simply sent your due each Monday while you do whatever you feel like doing.

That you're an active participant of your career path not just an ex-member is reinforced by the fact that you progress according to your career, and you most likely enter new basic/advanced careers as time passes in the campaign world. For example, the Basic Considerations of the core book (p.28) cautions that you can't become the Steward of a castle and then leave for 6 months on an adventure, unless your GM says so. Which implies you should be getting paid if you manage to successfully take on the Steward career at a castle — especially if you don't leave for 6 months (unless you do it at the request of the Lord of the castle.)

My question is:

**Do WFRP 2nd edition PCs earn an income based on Table 5-1: Income (p.104) from their career besides what they earn (and loot) while adventuring?**

Sure, I can decide this as a GM, but I'd like to know the official take or recommendation which I tried to yet couldn't find in the core book. If it's there, please, give me a page number.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on the environment.

If the players are on tour then it's hard for a physician to make money, unless MG allow players to join a group of merchant.
If the players are in town then they can earn money from their career but only if they are doing it and not in story telling.
I mean its hard to do the job when you are doing quest with a team.

The career income are mostly used when there is a time leaps between campaigns.

At least its how we are playing.